# Дата заполнения строки

Tags: sql

Как в SQL PLUS сделать так, что бы по умолчанию в столбце прописывалась автоматически дата заполнения соответствующей строки? `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` и `DEFAULT SYSDATE` ошибки не выдает, но и не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Заполнить `DEFULT` значение. Или написать триггер на `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

DEFAULT GETDATE()

Comment: если запись хранится в datetime можно попробывать `DEFAULT NOW()`